# Fetch App referrer when iOS App opened from other iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

Did some research but haven't found way to detect app referrer in iOS app(App is based on Swift Language), Flow is

- Someone has posted some web link on FB i.e. link is
  https://example.com.
- Assume our iOS app is already installed on user's
  device, hence when someone click on that link it will trigger ourapp(via
  deep linking flow), and its working fine but also would like to know 
  source from which app user land to our iOS app.

Looks like in android there is way to achieve this using AndroidAppUri but haven't found way for iOS, let me know if anybody has any suggestion\input.

Comment: Try [Branch.io](https://branch.io/).

Comment: Also you could generate campaign link here: https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/#/campaigngenerator?app=Your-App-ID

Comment: Thanks Zaid for your reply, can you share  reference article for branch.io which support this? so can check , so far haven't found. Regarding campaign generator its not necessary that on 3rd party app our app link will be posted, it can be any article from our site, but due to deep linking when user tap that article link it will land to our app. Thanks